# What's the most commom GoP length for videos?

Tags: iptv

I'm looking for the most commom GoP length used by IPTV system, or videos in general.

Answer (score 0):

In the research area I did not found for IPTV system but I found this article that told me an idea of GOP Lenght in LTE Networs: "GOP Length Effect Analysis on H.264/AVC Video Streaming Transmission Quality over LTE Network", witch is varible from 2 to 35. And the optimal length was between 5-8.

For me (personal use because I'm working in a Telco operator)  the most commom in the IPTV systems is the 12,2, witch means 12 frames between I (intra-frames) and 2 frames "B" (bidirectional frames) between "P" frames.

Answer (score 0):

Most common GOP length is 10 , Rest is depend on your type of streams , video codecs etc etc